# Angular 4 Popover bootstrap

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

How can I change the size of popover in bootstrap 4?  I try in HTML but it do not  work for me.

I am using:

```
 <ng-template   #popContent  popoverClass="T">
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've got 2 options depending on your use-case:

- if you want to change width of *all* your popovers than just customize Bootstrap's CSS by overriding Sass properties;
- if you want to just change width of one instance you can target elements with the `.popover` class and override the `max-width` property.

Example:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'ngbd-popover-basic',
  templateUrl: 'src/popover-basic.html',
  styles: [`
    :host >>> .popover {
      max-width: 500px;
    }
  `]
})
export class NgbdPopoverBasic {
}
```

A fully working example in a plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/XHK5lN6VZlp2vwlEsKBS?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

in your component.scss add :

```
:host /deep/ .popover{
    left: 0% !important;
    width: 100% !important;
    max-width: 500px !important;
 }
```

it gives you warning but work perfectly.

**point to remember : in component.ts file you can either use external css or** style component